# Parsing JSON data using variables as keys

Tags: php, json

I am getting a JSON response which looks like this:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [location00] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id_0] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Wanted by Aryurumoka
                    [gold_reward] => 58900
                    [event] => 0
                    [description] => Not provided.
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

For example, i am able to get `[name]` by `$quests->location00[0]->id_0[0]->name`.

Lets say i create a new variable `$location = 'location00'`. Now if i try `$quests->$location[0]->id_0[0]->name'`, i am getting `Undefined property: stdClass::$l` error. I tried `$location = 'location00[0]'` as well however i have completly no idea why this happenes. How can i assign `location00` to variable to use it while parsing JSON?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to get new JSON, but you can interpolate object property retrieval with braces:

```
$quests->{$location}[0]
```

Comment: Ahh, nice, this worked perfectly. Since i am quite new to parsing JSON, could you please explain or give link to manual that explains purpose of braces?

Comment: @lolbas this has nothing to do with JSON specifically ... it's just a PHP syntax thing.

Comment: @lolbas This is a PHP concept called [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @lolbas actually you need the braces so that the variable interpolation is done first.  If you do `$quests->$location[0]` it would be similar as if you did `$quests->{$location[0]}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use associative array or $obj->{$var} :

```
<?php
$quests = json_decode($json, true);
$location = 'location00';
$name = $quests[$location][0]['id_0'][0]['name'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Using data as array is really cool, however i am trying to start working with objects. +1 though